# Mabinogi talent probs

Tags: mabinogi

Um, I've played mabinogi for a while now, and I'm just wondering, I'm lvl 61 but still have a brown box around my talent. Shouldn't it be silvery? My talent is Fighter, and shouldn't I have the title of "Apprentice Fighter" instead of "Naive Fighter"? 
I hope someone can explain this for me. Thank you very much for your time ~

Answer (score 1):

Each Talent gains experience and levels as you rank skills that are associated with it.
For example the Fighter talent gets experience from all of the following skills:

- Knuckle Mastery
- Chain Mastery
- Tumble
- Respite
- Focused Fist
- Charging Strike
- Spinning Uppercut
- Somersault Kick
- Drop Kick
- Pummel
- Counter Punch (which is the only skill in a different skill tab, its under the hidden skill tab)

The following link will show you the Martial arts category (which is the fighter talent) list and you can click the "skill Talent Experience" tab to view how much exp each skill gives to the talent each time you rank it.  At the top of that page you can view how much experience total you need for each talent rank.

http://wiki.mabinogiworld.com/view/Talent#Martial_Arts

Comment: No problem at all. Feel free to mark this as the Answer if it covered all of your questions. If it didn't feel free to let me know and I can edit my answer.